# How to enhance MSER for text detection in ocr

Tags: java, android, opencv, image-processing, google-vision

`private void sgmnt(Mat mImg) {

```
    Imgproc.cvtColor(msImg, m2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Mat mRgba = mImg;
    Mat mGray = m2;

    Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(1, 255, 128, 0);
    //Scalar CONTOUR_COLOR = new Scalar(255);
    MatOfKeyPoint keyPoint = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    List<KeyPoint> listPoint = new ArrayList<>();
    KeyPoint kPoint = new KeyPoint();
    Mat mask = Mat.zeros(mGray.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    int rectanx1;
    int rectany1;
    int rectanx2;
    int rectany2;
    int imgSize = mGray.height() * mGray.width();
    Scalar zeros = new Scalar(0,0,0);

    List<MatOfPoint> contour2 = new ArrayList<MatOfPoint>();
    Mat kernel = new Mat(1, 50, CvType.CV_8UC1, Scalar.all(255));
    Mat morByte = new Mat();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();

    Rect rectan3 = new Rect();

    FeatureDetector detector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.MSER);
    detector.detect(mGray, keyPoint);
    listPoint = keyPoint.toList();
    for(int ind = 0; ind < listPoint.size(); ++ind) {
        kPoint = listPoint.get(ind);
        rectanx1 = (int) (kPoint.pt.x - 0.5 * kPoint.size);
        rectany1 = (int) (kPoint.pt.y - 0.5 * kPoint.size);

        rectanx2 = (int) (kPoint.size);
        rectany2 = (int) (kPoint.size);
        if (rectanx1 <= 0) {
            rectanx1 = 1;
        }
        if (rectany1 <= 0) {
            rectany1 = 1;
        }
        if ((rectanx1 + rectanx2) > mGray.width()) {
            rectanx2 = mGray.width() - rectanx1;
        }
        if ((rectany1 + rectany2) > mGray.height()) {
            rectany2 = mGray.height() - rectany1;
        }
        Rect rectant = new Rect(rectanx1, rectany1, rectanx2, rectany2);
        try{
            Mat roi = new Mat(mask, rectant);
            roi.setTo(CONTOUR_COLOR);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            Log.d("mylog", "mat roi error " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }

    Imgproc.morphologyEx(mask, morByte, Imgproc.MORPH_DILATE, kernel);
    Imgproc.findContours(morByte, contour2, hierarchy, Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);
    for(int i = 0; i<contour2.size(); ++i){
        rectan3 = Imgproc.boundingRect(contour2.get(i));
        if(rectan3.area() > 0.5 * imgSize || rectan3.area()<100 || rectan3.width / rectan3.height < 2){
            Mat roi = new Mat(morByte, rectan3);
            roi.setTo(zeros);
        }else{
            Imgproc.rectangle(mRgba, rectan3.br(), rectan3.tl(), CONTOUR_COLOR);
        }
    }
}Output`[![ ][1]][![]][1]
```

In segmentation button I use MSER/Maximally stable extremal regions using opencv lib. How could I enhance segmentation using some algorithms? Should I segment it per character,word or some smoothing etc. before passing to text recognition of tesseract. It is my final proj for school.

Comment: This question can have several possible answers and it depends on the images what works best for you. Can you update your question with what exactly you are doing at the moment?

Comment: @RickM. Im segmenting it to smaller pieces.